# Clone Laravel Proyect

Tags: laravel, localhost, url-routing

i try to copy laravel proyect (server to localhost) but the proyect don't have any documentation. i copy the proyect in new laravel proyect and work i think, becouse it show the login, but when i try to get in i get this error

[image]

the url is diferent because in the login show this

http://localhost/cresi/laravel/public_html/transacciones/

in the server doesn't exist the folder webservices, i think is internal url but i don't know how check this.

thanks for your advises

regards

Comment: check your `.env` file in your root folder. Most likely the URL is wrong there. You may want to look at the [https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the `.env` file values to make it work on your machine.
Most likely the `APP_URL` is wrong in there.

You can learn more about what is going wrong by looking at the doc at https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation

Comment: Hi, @Christophe Hubert , i copied the .env fiel onli change database user and password but doesn't work. the line APP_URL=http://localhost is the same in production

Comment: Change it to APP_URL=localhost/cresi/laravel/public_html/ to make it work for your config